Specialized dictionary for Chinese maths terms
I am looking for a specialized dictionary for general and even more advanced maths terms (whenever available), either an online resource (website/application) or a book in print which I can buy. The Pleco dictionary on my phone remains silent even for more common sense terminology such as "integration" and "differentiation". It doesn't matter for me so much to which target language the Chinese terms are translated, either German, English or French is fine.
To see what I have in mind, I refer to this website which contains a list of Chinese maths terms with German translation, containing three pages, which is of course not at all extensive. I am looking for a much broader resource.
The ideal resource would include also example sentences of how I can use those Chinese maths terms in context as this is not clear at all by giving a single expression.

Wouldn't it be easier if you translate the maths terms from Engish, say, to Chinese?

Yes, of course. I rather meant this direction and made unnecessary confusion.

Wikipedia - Search and switch to Chinese.
Math Fandom Wiki. Similar to Wikipedia. Lots of languages included.
Baidu Wiki 百度百科 Search in English, and see if you get a math entry. If you get an English word entry like this, you can see if there is some math links down there.
Xiaoshi Wiki 小时百科. Another Chinese math and physics wiki.
Banana Space 香蕉空间 For some very advanced math. Incomplete. try this list and use the browser translation and search system, and see if it works.
Youdao dictionary 有道词典 Bing dictionary 必应词典 and all sorts of dictionaries. find the "[数]" and it means math.
Zhihu 知乎 Sometimes people write math passages here. They may or may not include the English. Maybe using this is just like using google.
Dictionary of Mathematics 数学大辞典 book.sciencereading.cn zlib A math dictionary. Looks very very promising. A LOT of mathematicians have participated making it.

btw, in Banana Space you can sometimes search German

Also, when we refer to names, we use the original name without any suffix. Like the Jacobian matrix, we say "Jacobi矩阵".

Thank you for the answer! Do you know if this dictionary 数学大辞典, you referenced, is bilingual English-Chinese or monolingual Chinese? I would like to know before I consider buying it.

I found out in the preview in the first link. No need to answer, thank you. This book looks really elaborated, great!

https://lsa.umich.edu/math/undergraduates/course-resources/chinese-english-math-glossary.html
I could find this terminology glossary for higher mathematics. It only includes Calculus I-III (of which Calculus III is multivariable calculus) and Probability.
https://www.edb.gov.hk/attachment/tc/curriculum-development/kla/ma/res/Glossary20200708.pdf
I also found this rather comprehensive glossary - however, it is in traditional characters, and I'm not sure if that is fine for you.
As for true dictionaries, apologies, I'm afraid that I'm not aware of any free resources in that manner.

Thank you! Traditional characters are also fine for me. I can convert them. Free resources or not, I would also be willing to pay for a book.

樂詞網 from National Academy for Educational Research of Taiwan is a good source for looking up Chinese terms.
https://terms.naer.edu.tw/
It comprises terms from numerous fields including mathematics. However you should be careful about the difference between terms in PRC and Taiwan.
